# multipage document pdf-lib.js with node & express

Tags: node.js, express

Im trying to create a multi-page document from templates on my file system, but I'm getting strange behaviour of the same page title across all pages in the document instead.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Something I don't quite get, is the way we add pages.  Why do we need to reference `newDoc` in the example below, when we do `await newDoc.copyPages(page, [0])`? Instead of just `newDoc.addPage(page)`?
Would it be that the form field named `Title` is being overwritten because both pages have the same field name during the copying of data streams?

**Note:** I've been made aware that StackOverflow doesnt have a tag for [pdf-lib.js.org](https://pdf-lib.js.org/), not to be confused with other pdf libraries.

```js
const payload = {
  rows: [{
    id: 1,
    title: 'Foo',

  },{
    id: 2,
    title: 'Bar'
  },
  formData: {
    hello: 'World',
    lorum: 'Ipsum'
  }
  ]
}

const makePdf = async (payload) => {
  const newDoc = await PDFDocument.create()
  newDoc.getForm().acroForm.dict.set(PDFName.of('NeedAppearances'), PDFBool.True)
  for (const row of payload.rows) {
    await addPage(row, payload.formData, newDoc)
  }
  return newDoc
}

const addPage = async (dataRow, formData, newDoc) => {
  const rowId = dataRow.id
  let templateName
  switch(true) {
    case (rowId === 1):
      templateName = 'foo'
    break
    case (rowId === 2):
      templateName = 'bar'
    break
  }
  const templatePath = path.join(__dirname, `../templates/pdfs_/${templateName}.pdf`)
  const template = await fs.readFileSync(templatePath)
  const page = await PDFDocument.load(template)
  const form = page.getForm()
  form.acroForm.dict.set(PDFName.of('NeedAppearances'), PDFBool.True)
  switch(templateName) {
    case 'foo':
      foo(form, formData)
    break
    case 'bar':
      bar(form, formData)
  }
  // dataRow.title logs correct strings ie: 'Foo' & 'Bar'
  form.getField('Title').setText(dataRow.title)
  const [firstPage] = await newDoc.copyPages(page, [0])
  return await newDoc.addPage(firstPage)
}

const bar = (form, formData) => {
  form.getField('Lorum').setText(formData.lorum)
}

const foo = (form, payload) => {
  form.getField('Hello').setText(formData.hello)
}

return makePdf(payload)

// Produces 2 page pdf with the same title
// [[ title: Foo, Hello: World ], [title: Foo, Lorum: Ipsum ]]
```

Comment: [ask] - What are you trying to achieve? Can you share the template sample?

Comment: Different text on each title field, on each page

Comment: See my answer, I think it's what you are looking for

Comment: @yeya thanks for replying.  Im trying to load a new template for each row, I see you have just one template for all pages.  It could work if I move the `loadTemplate` function into the `for` loop.  Also do you need to pass `pdfSample.templateDoc` to the `addDocPage` function? It's been a while since I used JS classes, but I'll try that and let you know if it works.

Comment: Yes, you can call loadTemplate for each file. No you don't need to padd the templateDoc because the loadTemplate is saved to `this` on each loadTemplate. Please accept the answer if it answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have your template file so I'm not sure excatly what you are trying to achieve.

The `copyPage` is indeed required.

You should save the `PDFDocument` before you change it again.

I tried to rewrite your code, I ignored the `PDFName` and `PDFBool` line but I'm sure you can get the idea.

```
const {PDFDocument} = require('pdf-lib');
const fs = require('fs');

const payload = {
    rows: [
        { id: 1, title: 'Foo', }, 
        { id: 2, title: 'Bar', },
    ], 
    formData: { hello: 'World', lorum: 'Ipsum', }
}

class PdfSample {

    async loadTemplate(templatePath) {
        const templateFile = fs.readFileSync(templatePath);
        const templateDoc = this.templateDoc = await PDFDocument.load(templateFile);
        this.templateForm = templateDoc.getForm();
    }

    async initDoc() {
        this.resultDoc = await PDFDocument.create();
    }

    fillTextField(fieldName, value) {
        const field = this.templateForm.getField(fieldName);
        field.setText(value);
    }

    get formFieldsNames() {
        return this.templateForm.getFields().map(field => field.getName());
    }

    async addDocPage() {
        const newPageBytes = await this.templateDoc.save();

        const newPage = await PDFDocument.load(newPageBytes);

        const [pageToAdd] = await this.resultDoc.copyPages(newPage, [0]);
        return this.resultDoc.addPage(pageToAdd);
    }

    async saveResult(outputPath) {

        const pdfBytes = await this.resultDoc.save();
        fs.writeFileSync(outputPath, pdfBytes);

    }
}

const pdfSample = new PdfSample();

(async () => {
    await pdfSample.initDoc();
    await pdfSample.loadTemplate('./pdfs_/OoPdfFormExample.pdf');

    console.log(pdfSample.formFieldsNames);

    for (const row of payload.rows) {
        pdfSample.fillTextField('Given Name Text Box', row.title);

        pdfSample.fillTextField('Family Name Text Box', payload.formData.hello);
        pdfSample.fillTextField('House nr Text Box', payload.formData.lorum);

        await pdfSample.addDocPage(pdfSample.templateDoc);
    }

    await pdfSample.saveResult('./pdfs_/result.pdf');
})();
```

The sample form is from [this site](http://foersom.com/net/HowTo/data/OoPdfFormExample.pdf)

Comment: I didn't use this class based code as I couldn't get it to work, but the answer is in this code.  You need to save the page bytes before copying to a new page `const newPageBytes = await page.save(); const newPage = await PDFDocument.load(newPageBytes); const [firstPage] = await newDoc.copyPages(newPage, [0]); newDoc.addPage(firstPage)`

Comment: Thanks. Where the bounty points went?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a document with two form fields named `Title`, one on each page. This does not work, both are the same field and show the same value.

Rather then "copy" existing fields from a template, you must use something like

```js
var newField = form.createTextField('Title' + dataRow.id);
newField.addToPage(firstPage, {x: ..., y: ...});
newField.setText(...);
```

Comment: I think he is trying to  change an existing field, not create a new one. Each row should be in a different page.